# How to find first and last appearance of one in boost::dynamic_bitset<>

Tags: c++, boost

I need indexes of first and last appearance of 1 in **boost::dynamic_bitset<>**, first is easy to find like  **size_type find_first() const**. How to find last, do I need to iterate or create new in reverse order or there is trick to find on easier way ?

Comment: Since there is not built in functionality to search for the last, either way you suggest (iteration (from last to first), or reversing followed by forward find) are both suitable solutions. Which one you should choose depends on what you find easier I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use some trick like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

int main()
{
   typedef boost::dynamic_bitset<>::size_type size_type;
   const size_type npos = boost::dynamic_bitset<>::npos;
   boost::dynamic_bitset<> bitset(10, 50);
   size_type first_idx = bitset.find_first();
   size_type current_idx = first_idx;
   if (first_idx != npos)
   {
      do {
         current_idx = bitset.find_next(current_idx);
      } while (bitset.find_next(current_idx) != boost::dynamic_bitset<>::npos);
      std::cout << bitset << " first: " << first_idx << " last: " << current_idx << std::endl;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've placed ticket for boost::dynamic_bitset with methods `find_prev()` and `find_last()`.
You can get this patch from boost trac: [Ticket #9352](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9352)